# Regroup variables by labels in ggplot2 without computing on the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to regroup some variables with the same label.

I can do it with pre-computing using `mutate`, for example I want to regroup versicolor and virginica Species and call the category "label2".

```
iris %>% 
  count(Species) %>% 
  mutate(code = 1, 
         Species = ifelse(Species == "setosa", "setosa", "label2")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(code, n, fill = Species)) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

But I wonder if this is possible to do directly with ggplot functions ?

Thanks

Comment: I would say no (at least it wouldn't look very different from your `ifelse`). I'd recommend splitting data processing (using `levels() <- `) and plotting.

Comment: *(grumbling)* And one more thing: that piping directly into `ggplot` doesn't seem very natural to me. Mixing `%>%` and `+` and the fact that data frame silently becomes ggplot object makes me feel uneasy about the whole paradigm and its' influence.

Comment: @tonytonov, I have to admit that I, too, pipe dplyr-manipulated data right into ggplot - I just find it really handy to modify the data for the plot without changing (reassigning) it permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the recode and then `ggplot`:

```
> iris$Species = factor(ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", "setosa", "label2"))
> ggplot(iris, aes(x=factor(1), fill=Species)) + geom_bar()
```

If you are bothered about overwriting `Species` then call it `Species2` or something.

Seems a lot clearer than all that piping. If you really don't want to touch the data frame, then this (with a bit of extra tidying up of labels):

```
 ggplot(
    iris,
    aes(
        x=factor(""), 
        fill=factor(
           ifelse(
              Species == "setosa", "setosa", "label2"
           )
        )
    )
 ) + geom_bar() + xlab("") + labs(fill="Species")
```